# .htaccess RewriteRule from download.php?token=something into /download/something

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this URL:
`http://www.example.com/subf/subf2/download.php?token=6309838552568`
It is possible to rewrite this url into this url? 
`http://www.example.com/subf/subf2/download/6309838552568`

**Note:** If someone types a URL like this:
`http://www.example.com/subf/subf2/download/6309838552568/sbuf3/subf4`
i want to show them an error page.

**Answer below**

**Hint**: Include files like JS and CSS need to be refer in absolute paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT/subf/subf2/` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subf/subf2/

RewriteRule ^(download)/(\w+)/?$ $1.php?token=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# to take care of css, js, images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$
RewriteRule ^download/(.+)$ /subf/subf2/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already a .htaccess file in the application folder http://www.example.com/subf/subf2/.htaccess, so i thought i edit your last line, but it doesn't work:  `RewriteRule ^(download)/(\w+)/?$ /$1.php?token=$2 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: I edited my code above, this rule can now go in `/subf/subf2/.htaccess`

Comment: Ok, much better, i can access it now trough the url, but 2 things more: 1.) I can't access my GET-Paramter token now(in download.php there's just this `echo $_GET['token']` and 2.) i don't want to use absolutes paths as in the rewritebase, is there a opportunity to use a relative path or to replace the rewritebase string with a variable?

Comment: Sry, number 1 isn't right. I can access the get-paramter, but the css and js-script no more.

Comment: `/subf/subf2/` is indeed the relative paths only, not full path since DOCUMENT_ROOT is not included in RewriteBase. However you can comment RewriteBase line and it should still work.

Comment: Congrats! js, css, images etc is most common problem people face when they swith to pretty URLs. Fix is easy. Make sure you always use absolute paths in them i.e. `src` starting from `http://` or `/`

Comment: Ops, didn't want to upvote this, cause i have still the same problem. This is a sample of the jquery include into the download.php file: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/tmpl/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/tmpl/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` will work fine since it is using absolute path. Check your page in firebug and see which css, js, image are showing 404

Comment: He can find no file. My files are in /var/www/sub/sub2/ (debian apache2). If I use an absoluth path like: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/sub/sub2/tmpl/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` then it can find the js-file, but what if I move the file into a other subfolder. i don't want to edit the source for such a change, i want to use relative paths. any ideas? btw thanks for your support!

Comment: Ok can you tell me some samples of css, js paths that are now causing 404 (You can use Firebug in Chrome or Firefox)

Comment: If I add `/sub/sub2` before every path(same for ajax calls, images, etc), then it works perfectly, or what do you mean?

Comment: nope, still not working :/ I mean, i can't be the only one with this problem. I have a download.php in %HOST%/sub/sub2. In this folder I have /tmpl/js/jquery.js. My declaration of the js file in the download.php is as you know "tmpl/js/jquery.js".

Comment: As I said (and you can see from dozens of answers I provided) that this is the most common problem people face after switching to pretty URL. And fix is also easy they start to use absolute paths as I suggested and problem is gone. You can also fix your problem by using `src=//sub/sub2/tmpl/js/jquery.js` in your JS file. But the problem is you don't to take this easy route of fixing your problem.

Comment: I want to run this script on multiple webserver with multiple subfolders, so editing all scripts on each webserver is a bit costly. i have a config file, should i just put a new parameter into it like path_to_application, would you recommend me this?

Comment: Yes that's a very good idea to keep this path in a config file, that will require change at one place only.

Comment: Well then, thanks for your help and your rewrite rule up there.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you. Upvoted your question for making that note about css, js etc.